# Error using ggplot2 in R Shiny: cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

this is my first stackoverflow question... thanks in advance!

I'm making a Shiny App that first does dplyr's count() on my data frame according to a user-inputted column name and then makes a simple ggplot2 bar plot with it. I'm sure passing the column name as a string is not a good idea, but I chose to implement it that way because I wasn't sure how to make the list of choices not include all the possible columns. That might not matter anyhow -- I don't really know what I'm doing!

This code causes the following error message in Shiny: "Error using ggplot2 in R Shiny: cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'"

```
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

colA <- rep(c("Apple", "Apricot", "Anchovy"), 2:4)
colB <- rep(c("Bear", "Barracuda", "Bat"), c(1,3,5))
colC <- rep(c("Consumes", "Crunches", "Chews"), c(1,6,2))
test_df <- data.frame(colA, colB, colC)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      # For whatever reason, I don't want to allow the user to choose colC
      selectInput("selection", label = "Choose column",
                  choices = list("Column A" = "colA",
                                 "Column B" = "colB"),
                  selected = "colA"
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput(barplot)
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  dataSelection <- reactive(test_df %>% count(!!sym(input$selection)))
  output$barplot <- renderPlot({
    dataSelection() %>%
      ggplot(aes(x = dataSelection[1], n))+
      geom_bar(stat="identity")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Do you have guidance on what the right way to approach this is? There's got to be a really simple answer out there that I'm missing, but my internet search was unsuccessful. I read a bit about how tidy evaluation causes issues in cases like this, but I couldn't understand it. Please enjoy the silly reprex. Thank you for any insights!

Comment: `dataSelection` is a reactive object. You need to use `dataSelection()` to get it's current value -- this goes for the `aes()` part as well. But `ggplot` dosen't really like you to pass vectors of values to `aes()`. If you need something more flexible, you can use the `.data` pronoun: `dataSelection() %>% ggplot(aes(x = .data[[input$selection]], n))+ geom_col()`

Answer (score 1):

Two issues:

1. `plotOutput()` takes the output ID as a string.
2. Your `ggplot2` `aes` call must take the variable *name* (not data), either as a symbol (using `aes`) or as a string (using `aes_string`).

Here is a working version of your sample app

```
ui <- fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            # For whatever reason, I don't want to allow the user to choose colC
            selectInput(
                "selection", 
                label = "Choose column",
                choices = list("Column A" = "colA", "Column B" = "colB"),
                selected = "colA")),
        mainPanel(plotOutput("barplot"))
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    dataSelection <- reactive(test_df %>% count(!!sym(input$selection)))
    output$barplot <- renderPlot({
        dataSelection() %>%
            ggplot(aes_string(x = input$selection, "n"))+
            geom_col()
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```